# Magento 1.9 additional information from vendor profile(marketplace) to order view (in admin)

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I've been struggling for the past 2 days for searching and trying to get some information displayed on order view on admin side.

I'm using an extension that lets customer to register as seller.
They can add products and and have sales.

Now real problem, in order view I can only see the order shipping address. And i would like to include the original "seller" address into the order view.

There is some code that displays seller address on his profile.

```
?php 
$seller_data = $this->getSellerData();
$shop_address = (array)json_decode($seller_data['shop_address']);

if(!empty($shop_address)) {
    $seller_data['address']['line1'] = $shop_address['line1'];
    $seller_data['address']['line2'] = $shop_address['line2'];
    $seller_data['address']['city'] = $shop_address['city'];
    $seller_data['address']['state'] = $shop_address['state'];
    $seller_data['address']['country'] = $shop_address['country'];
    $seller_data['address']['pincode'] = $shop_address['pincode'];
}

if (isset($seller_data['page_url_key']) && !empty($seller_data['page_url_key'])) {
    $seller_view_link = Mage::getUrl($seller_data['page_url_key']);
} else {
    $seller_view_link = Mage::getUrl('marketplace/sellers/view', array('id' => $seller_data['seller_id']));
}

if(isset($seller_data['payment_info']) && !empty($seller_data['payment_info'])){
    $seller_data['payment_info'] = unserialize($seller_data['payment_info']);
} 
?>
```

Some guidance? I'm clueless after trying different options.